# Get Json inside a json and put it in the textboxes using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have an output like this.

```
[{…}]
0:
id: 3
url_generation: "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#sent"
status: "status one"
certificate: "[{"med_sbj_list":"Certificate1"},{"med_sbj_list":"Certificate2"},{"med_sbj_list":"Certificate3"},{"med_sbj_list":null},{"med_sbj_list":null},{"med_sbj_list":null}]"
name: "Doctor 1"
alphabet_name: "Doctor one"
image: "/doctor_photos/GSmdfr_Screenshot_20200114_102036.jpg"
image_caption: "this is an image caption"
image_alt: "image alt"
industry: "industry two"
conference: "[{"conf":"Conference1"},{"med_sbj_list":"Conference2"},{"conf":"Conference3"},{"conf":null},{"conf":null},{"conf":null}]"
birthday: "03-6-2018"
place_of_birth: "cebu city"
career_academic_back: "[{"from_year":"1991","from_month":"02","from_desc":"aaa","to_year":"1995","to_month":"06","to_desc":"bbb"}]"
career_work_exp: "[{"we_from_year":"1997","we_from_month":"05","we_from_desc":"ccc","we_to_year":"1997","we_to_month":"06","we_to_desc":"ddd"}]"
career_awards: "[{"from_year":"1998","from_month":"08","from_desc":"eee","to_year":"1999","to_month":"09","to_desc":"fff"}]"
sort_career: "1"
hospital_office: "industry one"
department: "[{"med_sbj_list":"industry one"},{"med_sbj_list":"industry one"},{"med_sbj_list":"industry one"},{"med_sbj_list":"industry one"},{"med_sbj_list":"industry one"},{"med_sbj_list":"industry one"}]"
doctor_comment: "this is a sample comment of the doctor."
created_at: "2020-01-22 03:50:28"
updated_at: "2020-01-22 03:50:28"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

And I want to get the `certificate` and `conference` value that are in json type and put it in the textboxes individually. See picture below.

[image]

These is my jquery code.

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/modal_edit_doctor/'+id,
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response['data']);
                if(response == "success")
                  console.log(response['data']); 
                  $("#editdoctor").modal('show');
                  $("#url_generation").val(response['data'][0].url_generation);
                  $("#status").val(response['data'][0].status);
                  var objJSON = JSON.parse(response['data'][0].certificate);
                  console.log(objJSON);


                    $("#name").val(response['data'][0].name);
                    $("#alpha_name").val(response['data'][0].alphabet_name);
                    //image not included yet
                    $("#img_caption").val(response['data'][0].image_caption);
                    $("#img_alt").val(response['data'][0].image_alt);
                    //industry dropdown not included yet
                    //conference json not included yet
                    //birthday not included yet
                    $("#place_birth").val(response['data'][0].place_of_birth);
                    //the 3 careers not included yet
                    //checkbox not included yet
                    //hospital dropdown not included yet
                    //department json not included yet
                    $("#doc_comment").val(response['data'][0].doctor_comment);


                },
                    error: function(response){
                    alert('Error'+response);

                }

              });
```

Comment: Then show us your jQuery code.

Comment: Do you want to convert value string to json ? then parse it `JSON.parse(certificate)` and loop through each to display

Comment: $.each(object.certificate, function( index, value ) {
  console.log(value.med_sbj_list);
}); will print all med_sbj_list under certificate

Comment: `JSON.parse(data)` in your success method parse your whole data variable and then loop through specific data you want, and it will be available to you.

Comment: @RiteshKhandekar I've updated my code above.

Comment: @SameerKhan I've updated my code above sir.

Comment: @AlokMali I've updated my code above sir

Comment: @AkhtarMunir I've updated my code above sir

Comment: But what is the actual problem you are facing ?

Comment: You cannot use if(response == "success"). because response is an array/object type.

Comment: @RomiHalasz i want to get the data that has a json result and put it individually in textbox

Comment: @angel1108 have you looked at the answer below?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir okay sir I will try your code below sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through it `objJSON` and you will access the data. I think you want this.

```
#textboxes is your text field id, maybe value or text you want to display.
$.each(objJSON, function(key,value){
   $("#textboxes").text(value.med_sbj_list);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

this will be like this i am not good at jquery but i'll write EJS

use this to get idea

var certificate1 = document.getElementbyId('certificate1')

certificate1.innerHTML = <%=response.certificate[0].med_sbj_list %>

you have to get the ceritificate  row first as you can see the certificate row is an array so use it like array to access it.

Comment: she is using jquery not EJS dear, your answer should be related to the actual question.